# Nested submenus are overlapping how do i fix?

Tags: css

http://bootply.com/68820 Nested submenus are overlapping how do i fix? Thank you.

html

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
            <li>
                <a href="#">2-level Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">t</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">t</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

css

```css
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}



.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
```

example: action should have 'a' and 'b' but they are showing submenu of next menu. Its just puzzling me. Someone help me . Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Apparently some people cannot access/use websites such as bootply or jsfiddle.  It would be helpful if you included your code in your question.

Comment: It's here Doorknob: http://bootply.com/68820. He has posted it. No need to down-vote the first timer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Tieson it doesn't say anywhere on that page that you can not post your code in jsfiddle ot bootply.

Comment: @Learner [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: I know that very well Antony. I was talking about the link that Tieson Posted. Point is he could have posted the link that you posted but his link does not mention anything about why not to post external links.

Answer (score 2):

use this html link is http://bootply.com/68830

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
            <li>
                <a href="#">2-level Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li><li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">t</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">t</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

and this css

```
    .dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li:hover >  .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}




.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
}
```

Comment: But now it doesnt displaying submenu for next menu :/

Comment: I have 't' 't' submenu for 'another action" its not displaying :/

Comment: the code has been updated here and so as link please check it

Comment: Thanx much that was so quick, one more thing how do i display them relative they are display at fixed postion on top

Comment: Beside the relative menu

Comment: add these lines in css .dropdown-menu li {
position:relative;
}

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study over the css that you changed :)